# C# Unity 3D Changing a variable(s) when bumping into another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am trying to have a set of variables be set in my "Player" when he bumps into a certain object (in this case a regular cube).  I also want it to only happen once and not to keep adding these values every time the player bumps into the object.

This is my player code that is declaring the variables that I want to change:

```
public class PlayerInfo : MonoBehaviour {
public static string Name;
public static int Level;
public static int Health;
public static int Damage;
public static float moveSpeed;

public float turnSpeed;
}
```

Then I have the object that the 'Player' will bump into starting with:

```
public class GiveHero : MonoBehaviour {

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //Code to assign Name, Level, Health, Damage, moveSpeed, as set values.
}
}
```

So I need the code below to assign the values from the code above.  They are two separate objects and in two separate sheets of code.

Thanks a bunch ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking those properties as `static` makes your job easy :-)

For example, decreasing the health:

```
PlayerInfo.Health -= 1;
```

Although I'm not sure if making them static is the correct approach, this code would work in your case ^.

Comment: This was the code I was looking for initially thank you! And nate_moyer's response rounds up my other issue with it happening once.  I wish I could mark both of your responses as correct.  I +1 both though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to changing the PlayerInfo variables as described in Yotam's answer, you'll need a way to ensure that this change happens only once.  You can do this in a variety of ways, some if which will fit your project better than others.  You might try:

1. Creating a boolean variable on the game object that will go from False to True when the player has collided with it.
2. Destroying the game object once it's collided with the player and changed the appropriate PlayerInfo variables.

Comment: looks like you never finished writing the code in this answer.  Could you please update it to include the full code snipper, and format the code into a code block?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changed all of your variables to be private instance variables and using a function to change their values when requested.  Defining them as static will cause problems if you need to use the script to define stats for multiple players.  It is also common practice to reference instance variables indirectly through functions instead of directly calling out the variable name.

```
public class PlayerInfo : MonoBehaviour {
    private string Name;
    private int Level;
    private int Health;
    private int Damage;
    private float moveSpeed;
    private float turnSpeed;

    public void SetHealth(int newHealthValue){
        Health += newHealthValue;
    }
    public void SetLevel(int newLevelValue){
        Level += newLevelValue;
    }
}
```

Based on nate_moyer's answer, put a check inside the collision function see if the action should be performed.

```
public class GiveHero : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool hasCollided = false;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if(!hasCollided){
            GetComponent<PlayerInfo>().SetHealth(-1); // Decrement the player's health by one.
            hasCollided = true;
        }
     }
}
```

or if you want to destroy the object your player touched:

```
    public class GiveHero : MonoBehaviour {
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        GetComponent<PlayerInfo>().SetHealth(-1); // Decrement the player's health by one.
        Destroy(other.gameObject); // Remove the Game Object the player collided with.
     }
}
```